# Why does clicking expand button closes the side panel in react?

Tags: reactjs

i have a side panel with items listed. when the list item content overflows expand button appears and clicking that expand btn would show the entire content of list item

For this i have created a expandable component. this will show arrow_down when list item content overflows and clicking arrow_down shows up arrow_up.

However with the below code, clicking button 1 just makes the sidpanel disappear instead of arrow_up appearing. could some one help me solve this. thanks.

```
export default class Expandable extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.expandable_ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
           expanded: false,
           overflow: false,
        };
     }

    componentDidMount () {
        if (this.expandable_ref.current.offsetHeight < 
             this.expandable_ref.current.scrollHeight) {
             this.setState({overflow: true});
        }
    }

    on_expand = () => {
        this.setState({expanded: true});
        console.log("in expnad");
    };

    on_collapse = () => {
        this.setState({expanded: false});
    };

    render () {

        return (
            <div className={(this.state.overflow ? 
            this.props.container_classname : '')}>
                <div className={(this.state.overflow ? 
                this.props.classname : '')} style={{overflow: 'hidden', 
                display: 'flex', height: (this.state.expanded ? null : 
                this.props.base_height)}}
                ref={this.expandable_ref}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                {this.state.overflow && this.state.expanded &&
                    <div className={this.props.expand}>
                        <button  onClick={this.on_collapse}> 
                            {this.props.arrow_up}</button>
                    </div>}
                {this.state.overflow && !this.state.expanded &&
                    <div className={this.props.expand}>
                        <button onClick={this.on_expand}> 
                            {this.props.arrow_down}</button>
                    </div>}

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

In the above code i pass the base_height to be 42px.

**Edit:**

i have realised for the side panel component i add eventlistener click to close the side panel if user clicks anywhere outside sidepanel. When i remove that eventlistener it works fine....

```
class sidepanel extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.sidepanel_ref = React.createRef();
    }

    handle_click = (event) => {
        if (this.sidepanel_ref.current.contains(event.target)) {
            return;
        } else {
            this.props.on_close();
        }
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handle_click, false);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handle_click, false);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="sidepanel" ref= 
                    {this.sidepanel_ref}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

when i log the event.target and sidepanel_ref.current i see the button element in both of them but svg seems different in both of them.

How can i fix this?

Comment: How is the side panel closed? Is there an `onClick` handler on an element that is an indirect parent of the button?

Comment: for that side panel i use addeventlistener(click, method) to close side panel clicking anywhere outside sidepanel. i shall edit the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is because click events bubble up the component tree as they do in the DOM too. If you have an element with an `onClick` handler inside an element with another `onClick` handler it will trigger both. Use `event.stopPropagation()` in the handler of the inner element to stop the event from bubbling up:

```
export default class Expandable extends React.PureComponent{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.expandable_ref = React.createRef();
        this.state = {
           expanded: false,
           overflow: false,
        };
     }

    componentDidMount () {
        if (this.expandable_ref.current.offsetHeight < 
             this.expandable_ref.current.scrollHeight) {
             this.setState({overflow: true});
        }
    }

    toggleCollapse = event => {
        // use preventDefault here to stop the event from bubbling up
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.setState(({expanded}) => ({expanded: !expanded}));
    };

    render () {
        const {className, container_classname, base_height, expand, arrow_up, arrow_down} = this.props;
        const {overflow, expanded} = this.state;

        return (
            <div className={overflow ? container_classname : ''}>
                <div 
                    className={overflow ? classname : ''} 
                    style={{
                        overflow: 'hidden', 
                        display: 'flex', 
                        height: expanded ? null : base_height
                    }}
                    ref={this.expandable_ref}
                >
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                {overflow && (
                    <div className={expand}>
                        <button onClick={this.toggleCollapse}> 
                            {expanded ? arrow_up : arrow_down}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks your answer could also be correct. but in my case, i replaced the addeventlister click to mousedown and it works...seems svg doesn't respond well to click events....

Comment: @niina That sounds like a patient got skin rash after a medication. As an svg is just another DOM element it behaves like every other DOM element on clicks. Also your handler in on the button, not the svg. Probably it is because your event listener is outside of the react render cycle. So react doesn't know about it and the moment it is executed, your button element has already re-rendered and the originally clicked one is therefore not considered inside the panel element. Click events on buttons should usually not bubble up, so `stopPropagation` is the save bet.

Comment: @niina My bad, it must of course be `stopPropagation`, not `preventDefault`.